# How to subset data using non-numerical criteria in r?

Tags: r, subset, sapply, large-data

Hi I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
    cond image name stim resp   con imgrey num
1 anim  mamm   fd    1    1 0.025 163.75  73
2 anim  mamm   fd    1    1 0.025 130.50 154
3 anim  mamm   fd    1    1 0.025 164.75   9
4 anim  pow    fd    1    1 0.025 186.25 202
5 anim  pow    fd    1    1 0.025 181.50 178
```

Except it has 3360 rows in total, I have to create a new data file, which shows rows in which the image is "pow", I am quite new to this and struggling to figure out how to subset my data with "pow" as a criteria for keeping.
I've tried

```
newdata <- subset(mydata, image== pow, select=c(cond, name, stim, resp, con, imgrey, num))
mysample <- mydata[sample(1:ncol(mydata) , mamm, replace=F) ,]
```

but like I said I'm (very) new to using r, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: just do `newdata <- mydata[image=="pow", ]`. you need to quote the string "pow", else, R will search for a variable called `pow`.

Comment: `subset(mydata, image== "pow")`

Comment: newdata <- mydata[image=="pow", ] gives an error:
Error in image == "pow" : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Comment: @FreyaDaisy, yes, sorry, I typed my comment to quickly, you need to do `newdata <- mydata[mydata$image=="pow", ]`

Answer (score 1):

```
df
  cond image name stim   con imgrey num
1 anim  mamm   fd    1 0.025 163.75  73
2 anim  mamm   fd    1 0.025 130.50 154
3 anim  mamm   fd    1 0.025 164.75   9
4 anim   pow   fd    1 0.025 186.25 202
5 anim   pow   fd    1 0.025 181.50 178

df1<-df[!(df$image!=="pow"),]
df1
  cond image name stim   con imgrey num
4 anim   pow   fd    1 0.025 186.25 202
5 anim   pow   fd    1 0.025 181.50 178
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: why not just `subset(df,image=="pow")` or `df[df$image=="pow",]` ?

Comment: That was the first one that came to my mind, for some reason.

Comment: I have tried subset(df,image=="pow"), it gives this erro: Error in image == "pow" : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Comment: @OlliJ It would be great if you edit the condition into == for future reference. Voting up..

Comment: What is `!==` ? Or actually, why the double negative? Why not `df[df$image=='pow',]`?